# How we pass blob data as a JSON object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, blob

```
var files = $('#File')[0].files;
var data = new Blob([files[0]]);
```

We need send this data along with JSON data in Ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

For uploading files over ajax you don't really have to care about blobs, you can simple use jquery snippet given below

Following snippet catches files from file upload control and attaches it to the data to be submitted in an ajax call.

```js
var data=[];
jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
});
```

And then you can use data in your ajax call to server.

Comment: JsEASE.js:2246 Uncaught TypeError: data.append is not a function
    at File.<anonymous> (JsEASE.js:2246)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at fnSubmitClaim (JsEASE.js:2245)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (ease.html:347)

Comment: @RenjithaRam It means you are not using jQuery here. you have to find another way to append to data. My example was related to jQuery.

Comment: @RenjithaRam Downvoting somebody who tried to give a solution won't give a correct solution.